# How to draw a line between two specifiy markers or two specific lat/lon?

Tags: here-api

I am using here maps to display points on the map and I would like to draw a line between two specific points.

I tried to `lineString.pushPoint` and combined to `Polyline`, but I only have a **linear result**. 
I would like to be able to link two existing markers to another existing one

Comment: Please provide a code example of what you have tried in practive before, so that we can follow your efforts. Without code it is extremely hard to come up with a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a marker at the start and/or endpoint like this:

```
function addPolylineToMap(map) {
  var lineString = new H.geo.LineString();

  lineString.pushPoint({lat:53.3477, lng:-6.2597});
  lineString.pushPoint({lat:51.5008, lng:-0.1224});
  lineString.pushPoint({lat:48.8567, lng:2.3508});
  lineString.pushPoint({lat:52.5166, lng:13.3833});

  map.addObject(new H.map.Polyline(
  lineString, { style: { lineWidth: 4 }}
  ));

  var startMarker = new H.map.Marker({lat:53.3477, lng:-6.2597});
  map.addObject(startMarker);

  var endMarker = new H.map.Marker({lat:52.5166, lng:13.3833});
  map.addObject(endMarker);

}
```